# Auto Generating a Div Structure with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Until today I have been using jsfiddle to design div's and then their CSS for testing purposes and then implement design to real development.

Now I wonder if there is any **GUI type** utility which I can use to generate a Div structure with CSS using GUI (nope am not talking about dream weaver or any other software like that).

**Example**

I want to make a div with four boxes in it, Is there any utility I can use where I can use "drag and drop" functionality to create a page layout and then get generated DIV structure.

**In Short I am Looking for a program where I can use my mouse to draw and then get div structure and CSS based on it, just like paint but then it should generate me a Div structure based on my drawing with CSS.**

**Update**

**Please don't get confused, as I don't want dream weaver, because of license, then it takes ages to open up.
I want something online, just like jsfiddle**

Must be free.

Comment: I think you actually *are* talking about Dreamweaver and other WYSIWYG editors.

Comment: @doublesharp read my question, I clearly said, I don't want dream weaver, but some online website, thanks

Comment: You didn't specify a web based tool in your question.

Comment: I updated my qestion, sorry for confusion

Comment: You say you don't want a HTML editor like DreamWeaver, but how is an online HTML editor different than that?

Comment: So, this would be a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one that comes to mind is [Webflow](http://webflow.com/), however it hasn't been released yet. You can sign up on their website to be notified when they launch, but it seems like they plan to offer most WYSIWYG editor features via a web interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think **Maqetta** is what you need.

Try it on http://r7.maqetta.org/ online for free, and it is opensource too.

Maqetta came out of an internal IBM initiative to address the visual design requirements of IBM’s various UXD teams. IBM contributed Maqetta’s original code to open source to foster a community that can help create and maintain a strong suite of open source HTML5 visual tools.

Here is a screenshot for example. there are many more features, enjoy !

[image]